# angular custom routerLink directive

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-directives, angular2-components

I'm trying to create my own directive (or component) which would internally use default angular `[routerLink]`. Idea is to have `[myRouterDirective]` which would do some magic and get parameters to fill to default angular `[routerLink]`.

I tried several approaches, but I have problems with all of them:

1. Ideal solution would be if angular directive could apply additional
   directives. This doesn't work AFAIK :(
2. Another way would be to create component which can use angularJS `replace: true` like feature. Replace is deprecated and is not supported in new angular...
3. Current appear to be working solution is to use element selector component and `<ng-content>`. It doesn't work well with CSS styles, as I need it to be `<a>` tag. (Styles have something like `.navigation>a` and having `<my-custom-element>` tag breaks it.
4. Another almost working solution is to use attribute selector component also with`<ng-content>`. It doesn't work as expected, because it adds new tag and does not modify the original one.

Is there any way which I'm missing how to do it?

Comment: what about `restrict`?

Comment: Could you please provide some more information? I don't know what exactly do you mean...

Comment: See; https://thinkster.io/directive-restrictions

Comment: But it is `AngularJS` (aka angular 1) feature, I'm using Angular 2. 
(Now being called just `angular` as recommended by angular team. I hate that decision, it makes a lot of confusion....)